# JS object: Iteration till nth level

Tags: javascript

I have the following sample object:

```
{
   "sampleA":{
      "sampleB1":{
         "sampleC1":{
            "sample1":"sample",
            "sample2":"sample",
            "sample3":"sample",
            "sample4":"sample",
            "sample5":"sample"
         },
         "sampleB2":{
            "sample1":"sample",
            "sample2":"sample sample",
            "sample3":"sample",
            "sample4":"sample sample",
            "sample5":"sample sample",
            "sample6":"sample"
         },
         "sampleB3":{
            "sample1":"sample",
            "sample2":"sample sample",
            "sample3":"sample sample",
            "sample4":"sample sample",
            "sample5":{
               "sample6":"sample",
               "sample7":"sample sample",
               "sample8":"sample sample",
               "sample9":"sample sample",
               "sample10":"sample",
               "sample11":"sample"
            },
            "sample100":"sample"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

It's a JS object that can be nested up to any level. I'm trying to iterate through the object and do some action:

Following is my code:

```
function isLeafNode(node) {
  if (typeof node == typeof "string") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

iterateObject(jsonData);

function iterateObject(obj) {
  for (var key in jsonData) {
    if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if(!isLeafNode(jsonData[key])){
        iterateObject(jsonData[key])
      }else{
        console.log("leaf node")
        //do something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the above code results in an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the local `obj` inside of `iterateObject` instead of the global `jsonData`.

```js
function iterateObject(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (!isLeafNode(obj[key])) {
                iterateObject(obj[key]);
            } else {
                console.log(key, "leaf node");
            }
        }
    }
}

function isLeafNode(node) {
    return typeof node === "string";
}

var data = { sampleA: { sampleB1: { sampleC1: { sample1: "sample", sample2:"sample", sample3:"sample", sample4:"sample", sample5:"sample" },sampleB2: { sample1: "sample", sample2:"sample sample", sample3:"sample", sample4:"sample sample", sample5:"sample sample", sample6:"sample" },sampleB3: { sample1: "sample", sample2:"sample sample", sample3:"sample sample", sample4:"sample sample", sample5:{ sample6: "sample", sample7:"sample sample", sample8:"sample sample", sample9:"sample sample", sample10:"sample", sample11:"sample" },sample100: "sample" } } } };

iterateObject(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in your below function

```
function iterateObject(obj) {
  for (var key in jsonData) {
    if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if(!isLeafNode(jsonData[key])){
        iterateObject(jsonData[key])
      }else{
        console.log("leaf node")
        //do something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It should be like below

```
function iterateObject(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if(!isLeafNode(obj[key])){
        iterateObject(obj[key])
      }else{
        console.log("leaf node")
        //do something
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You are using **jsonData** in loop instead of passed argument **obj**